# Noindex Buddypress pages - X-Robots tag

Tags: php, wordpress, indexing, robots.txt, buddypress

I'm trying de-index all the Buddypress pages like Photos, Groups, Profiles, Activity etc.

I was hoping to use something like the following function that adds an X-Robots tag into each page head.

```
function noindex_buddypress_pages() {
    if ( is_buddyPress() || bp_is_groups() ) {
        echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">';
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'noindex_buddypress_pages' );
```

Will this work or is there a better solution to do this?

Comment: why not modify `robots.txt` file? something like [this](https://buddypress.org/support/topic/hide-buddypress-pages-from-google-serch/)

Comment: Because you can't rely on robots.txt file on it's own. Very often it gets ignored by the robots anyway. Maybe not Google, but lots of the others.

Comment: Second to Mason's link, seems right solution to me.